# How to database-side declare default high-precision datetime default + onupdate with mysql

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, sqlalchemy

I am trying to declare `create_time` and `update_time` with high-precision (milli/micro-second precision) in a MySQL db. The problem is that I cannot find the right syntax/functions to get those two requirements running.

Assumptions/digging so far:

1. I've found the only way for high precision datetime for MySQL to use mysql  dialect `DATETIME(fsp=6)` (or `TIMESTAMP(fsp=6)`)
2. I need to use argument `server_default` for database to set default
3. I'm not sure how to set `ON UPDATE NOW(6)`

Here is a stripped down version of the table I am setting up:

```
from datetime import datetime

from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import DATETIME
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql import func


def create_declarative_base():
    base = declarative_base()
    base.__table_args__ = {
        'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB',
        'mysql_charset': 'utf8',
    }
    return base

Base = create_declarative_base()


class CreateUpdateTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'create_update_table'
    create_time = Column(DATETIME(fsp=6), server_default=func.now(), nullable=False)
    update_time = Column(DATETIME(fsp=6), server_default=func.now(), onupdate=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
```

When running this I get `Invalid default value for 'create_time'` as the `func.now()` is serialized to `create_time DATETIME(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT now()` but it needs to be `...now(6)`

I've also tried to do a simple `server_default='NOW(6)'` but that translates to `create_time TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'now(6)'` (where the expression is a string...)

Comment: Have you tried the `text` function like in the example [in the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.server_default)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a colleague that came up with a suggestion that also [@Terminus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5051310/terminus) hinted about, I got a nice solution for both problems:

```
from datetime import datetime


from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import DATETIME
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql import func


def create_declarative_base():
    base = declarative_base()
    base.__table_args__ = {
        'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB',
        'mysql_charset': 'utf8',
    }
    return base

Base = create_declarative_base()


class CreateUpdateTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'create_update_table'
    create_time = Column(DATETIME(fsp=6), server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)'), nullable=False)
    update_time = Column(DATETIME(fsp=6), server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)'), nullable=False)
```